# Preguntas con el mismo título

Tags: discusión

A raíz de esta pregunta: [¿Se puede pasar un operador como argumento de una función?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287113/se-puede-pasar-un-operador-como-argumento-de-una-funci%c3%b3n) se me ocurrió escribir la misma, pero aplicada a otro lenguaje, finalmente quedó esta otra: [¿Se puede pasar un operador como argumento de una función en R?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287195/se-puede-pasar-un-operador-como-argumento-de-una-funci%c3%b3n-en-r)

Lo que me llamó la atención, ya que nunca me había ocurrido, es que SO, no acepta preguntas con el mismo título, aunque las etiquetas sean distintas (no, tampoco se puede salvar y modificar luego)

Imagino que gestionar este cambio de funcionalidad debe ser inviable, y tal vez innecesario. Sin embargo, **¿qué criterio podemos usar con el nombre para no colisionar los títulos?**, por ejemplo, en estos casos bien puntuales, una pregunta interesante que dispara la posibilidad de crear una nueva versión  en otro lenguaje.

**Nota**: En este caso agregué `"en R"` para poder diferenciarlas, pero también está el critero de no agregar la etiqueta en el título (Un [Uróboros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur%C3%B3boros)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la [ayuda de SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pone lo siguiente: (las itálicas son mías)

> ### Escribe un título que resuma el problema específico
>
> El título es la primera cosa que los que potenciales contestadores verán, y si tu
>   título no es interesante, ellos no leerán el resto. Así que considera:
>
> - **Pretende que le estás hablando a un colega ocupado** y que tienes que resumir toda la pregunta en una oración: ¿qué detalles puedes
>     incluir que ayudarán a otros a identificar y resolver tu problema?
>     *Incluye cualquier mensaje de error, APIs clave o circunstancias
>     inusuales que hacen tu pregunta diferente de preguntas similares que
>     ya existen en el sitio.*
> - **¡La ortografía, la gramática y la puntuación son importantes!** Recuerda, esta es la primera parte de tu pregunta que otros verán -
>     quieres dar una buena impresión. Si no te sientes cómodo escribiendo
>     en Español, pregunta a un amigo que revise la lectura.
> - Si tienes problemas resumiendo el problema, **escribe el título al final** - algunas veces escribir el resto de la pregunta primero puede
>     facilitar a describir el problema.

El API, el lenguaje de programación o el entorno pueden ser buenos candidatos para ajustar el título y que no se repita. Entre los ejemplos que se dan en la propia página de ayuda está:

> **Mal**: [php] duda de sesión
>
> **Bien**: ¿Cómo puedo redirigir a los usuarios a diferentes páginas basado en datos de la sesión en PHP?

Comment: No se si estoy muy de acuerdo. Para mi, todo lo que sean etiquetas no deben ponerse en el título de la pregunta. En el caso que da origen a la pregunta, creo que simplemente replanteando el título el sistema lo admitiría (por ejemplo, algo como _¿Es posible pasar un operador como argumento de una función?_)